# How can I buy options for a stock that isn't listed on an options exchange?

Tags: stocks, options, options-exchanges

I looked up various data sources, but I was unable to find the option chain for a specific stock.

As an example, options for Berkshire Hathaway Class A stock (BRK-A) do not appear to trade on an options exchange.

Are there other ways I can buy options on such a stock?

Comment: Close voters please note that this is not asking for a specific recommendation, it is looking for a way of trading options on an underlying that doesn't have exchange traded options. This should be on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no exchange traded options for Berkshire A then the  only alternative  is a private  transaction on the the over-the-counter market.  These transactions are not guaranteed by  the OCC and the option exchanges. There's no secondary market so  there's almost way to adjust or close the trade other than with the original counterparty. Such agreements are for the big boys, not for retail trade.

Comment: Are FLEX options a possible alternative to over-the-counter options?

Comment: Sorry  but I have never looked into or utilized  Flex options.

Answer (score 0):

Options contracts are usually for 100 shares and the price of one share of Berkshire Hathaway Class A stock is $284,749.  So one option contract would relate to $28 million worth of the stock.   Most people who want to trade options on Berkshire Hathaway would buy options on the B shares.  Why would someone want to buy options in the A shares and not the B shares?

Exchange listed options generally require an underlying security to be not only listed on an exchange but also have to have sufficient liquidity.

Many options exchanges will list an options class in a new stock if there is sufficient interest and there is a market maker willing to make markets in the options.

It may be possible to buy an option over-the-counter (i.e. not on an exchange) through an OTCDD (over the counter derivatives dealer) but these are generally where a large bank takes the other side of the transaction to meet a client's specific requirements and some commission.

Comment: Are FLEX options a possible alternative to over-the-counter options?

Comment: Possibly, but ultimately there would need to be a market maker willing to take the other side of the trade (for something they wouldn't be able to sell easily later). There may also be some issues about listing options for an otherwise not listed security (BRK.A), so the exchange might not be willing to allow it.  Why not use BRK.B as a proxy for BRK.A instead? There is a high correlation between the two.